# Not able to Drag files from external devices(phone and pen drive) to WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik

I have implemented drag and drop functionality for rad grid view in WPF with telerik controls, I am able to drag files from local system but not able to drag files from external devices like phone and pendrive

Below is the code used

```
 private void OnElementDragOver(object sender, 
 Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.DragEventArgs e)
 {
    var files = (IEnumerable<string>)(e.Data as                                  
    DataObject).GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (files != null)
        {
            if (Resources.Enums.IsImageDrog(files))
            {
                string[] contact = (e.Data as 
                DataObject).GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop) as 
                string[];
                if (this.DataContext is TestResultLibraryVM && contact != 
                null)
                (this.DataContext as 
                TestResultLibraryVM).AddDroped(contact.OfType<string> 
                ().ToList());                    
            }     
        }
  }
```